# HA Proxy Load Distribution

Tags: haproxy

HI,

I am running haproxy for load balancing .. i have 2 web server behind the LB. My requirement is , to go 70% load to server 1 and remaining 30% to server2 ,

Please share the Configuration details if its possible,

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `weight` keywork to specify the server weight.

```
weight <weight>
```

You can try the algorithm `static-rr`.

Answer (score 0):

HaProxy implements a few different load portioning algorithms. The one we use is the *least connections* one "that picks the backend with the fewest pending connections." as discussed in this article:

http://affectioncode.wordpress.com/2008/06/11/comparing-nginx-and-haproxy-for-web-applications/

The algorithm is smarter than just applying a ratio a la nginx - it should portion out load based on what your back-ends can handle.